# Need to Alter data type in a column common to all tables in a schema

Tags: database, postgresql, alter-table, alter-column

I need to alter the Data Type of a named column (let's call them 'photo') across all the tables in a schema.

For example: I have 300 tables with identical structure (except the data in each row of course).
But I have to change the varchar(255) in the photo column to (500) on every table.
Is there a way to do it without going through every table and doing it manually?

I tried everything I found on the internet. Used ChatGPT (useless as always) but to no avail.

Comment: 1) Why not change to just `varchar`(no length restriction), then you won't have to do this again. 2) The way to do this is loop over the tables, pulling from `pg_class` and alter each in turn.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) I don't know. The DB was made in 2012 by a employee who's not on the workplace anymore. I'm trying to break the least things possible. 2) Could you help me? Never had to alter a big database before.

Comment: 1) What is Postgres version? 2) Are there tables in the schema that do not have the same structure as the 300 you want to change? 3) Do you have a dev instance of the database that you can test on? 4) How busy is the database?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1)   2) No, every table has the same structure 3) I've already created a backup to test queries 4) the database is only accessible locally by an application on a single laptop

Comment: @AdrianKlaver PostGre Version is 9.6, can't edit my comment.

Comment: 1) Postgres 9.6 is 2 years past EOL, see [Versioning](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). At some point fairly soon you will need to think about upgrading 2) What is the application? 3) Can  you use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-psql.html)?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1) Sure, the application will be upgraded too. I'll keep that in mind thanks 2) It's a custom WinForms application which uses the database to create PDFs 3) Yes

Comment: You have to run `ALTER TABLE` statements for all tables. I would change the type to `text`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, I'm aware of that. I just can't seem to find a way to apply this to all the tables in a schema.

Answer (score 1):

An example, obviously not tested on your instance, so try out on test database first. In `psql` do:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT format('ALTER TABLE %s ALTER COLUMN photo TYPE varchar', pg.oid::regclass)
FROM
(
 SELECT
    oid
 FROM
    pg_class
 WHERE
    relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
 AND
    relkind = 'r'
) pg
\gexec

--COMMIT; or ROLLBACK; depending on outcome
```

UPDATE

Per  Laurenz Albe's suggestion changed `relname` to `oid` in the sub-query and then `pg.relname` to `pg.oid::regclass` in the outer query as extra precaution against SQL injection.

Change the `relnamespace` value to the schema you are looking to change the tables in.

Comment: How would SQL injection occur if `relname` is coming directly from the sub-query?

Comment: I've read *Bobby Tables* and understand SQL injection. What I am interested in is where an outside party is capable of injecting *but here is something evil* in this case? `pg.relname` is coming from the the sub-query, I'm not seeing how it could be replaced?

Comment: I tried that and could not make it work. You will need to provide an example. I can see the utility of `oid::regclass` I just don't see how it would help here?

Comment: There is no room to provide an example in a comment. Anyway, you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This query on `information_schema` shows both the list of all tables with the column to be altered and in the last column the `ALTER` statement to perform the change.

Adjust the schema/column name as required.

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length,
format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I ALTER COLUMN %I TYPE text;', table_schema, table_name, column_name) sql_txt
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'jdbn'
   AND column_name  = 'photo'
order by table_name;
```

Sample output

```
table_schema|table_name                          |column_name|data_type        |character_maximum_length|
------------+------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------------+
jdbn        |Table2                              |photo      |character varying|                     200|
jdbn        |harmless; but here is something evil|photo      |character varying|                     300|
jdbn        |t1                                  |photo      |character varying|                     100|
```

Note that to [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) the `ALTER` statement the `I`  type is used, to avoid problems with mixed case names and SQL injection as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993860/need-to-alter-data-type-in-a-column-common-to-all-tables-in-a-schema#comment135733024_76994514).

I recommend for this ad hoc task a two step strategy:

1. copy the content of the last column in a text file.

`ALTER TABLE jdbn."Table2" ALTER COLUMN photo TYPE text;`

`ALTER TABLE jdbn."harmless; but here is something evil" ALTER COLUMN photo TYPE text;`

`ALTER TABLE jdbn.t1 ALTER COLUMN photo TYPE text;`

2. run it as a SQL script. Recheck the result with the query above and `commit` if OK.

Comment: Good. However, is there a negligible but non-zero probability that a table contains the column `photo` with data type other than character. If so avoid them by adding the predicate `and data_type like 'character%'`. Also there is no need to sort.

Comment: Good point @Belayer, this is exact why I prefere the *two step* approach. In the *visual inspection* of the first step such anomalies should be spotted;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DO $$
DECLARE
table_name text;
BEGIN
FOR table_name IN (SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 
'your_schema_name') LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN photo TYPE 
varchar(500);';
END LOOP;
 END $$;
```