# How to update type of all columns with the same name in all tables in one query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, information-schema

I'd like to assign type `timestamp without timezone` to all columns name `created_at` at my database scheme. I'm trying to run this query:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  table_name text;
BEGIN
  FOR table_name IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'created_at' AND table_schema = 'public' LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN created_at TYPE timestamp without time zone;';
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "table_name" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE colu...
               ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'created_at' AND table_schema = 'public'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at FOR over SELECT rows
SQL state: 42702
```

Guys, also please note, that if you want to edit it not in the `public`, but, say, `audit`, schema, change it accordingly:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  table_name text;
BEGIN
  FOR table_name IN SELECT columns.table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'created_at' AND table_schema = 'audit' LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE audit' || table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN created_at TYPE timestamp without time zone;';
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns. (At least when several tables are involved.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to Alter data type in a column common to all tables in a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993860/need-to-alter-data-type-in-a-column-common-to-all-tables-in-a-schema)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber not, it doesn't as it doesn't explain my problem with my script. And thus stop your attempts to close my querstion with the stuff that isn't actually answering

Comment: Column qualification might not always be enough. If you qualify all columns you'll still get a conflict when you attempt to use a variable which name is conflicting with one of them. In that case, [you need a label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77052013/5298879) to also qualify the variable. So, when in doubt, *qualify all the things*.

Comment: Read this [Variable substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST). It is the cause of your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify the ambiguous name

```sql
...  SELECT columns.table_name FROM information_schema.columns ...
```

Answer (score 1):

All object should be named unique

in your case the name table_name is part of the information schema as name of the variaböe

so rewrite it like this

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  p_table_name text;
BEGIN
  FOR p_table_name IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'created_at' AND table_schema = 'public' LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || p_table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN created_at TYPE timestamp without time zone;';
  END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you had an identifier conflict between the variable `table_name` and a column `table_name` in `information_schema.columns`.

Apart from JGH's suggestion to [qualify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-COLUMN-REFS) it and nbk's to rename it, it's good to know that there's also a [special command in plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#id-1.8.8.13.3.9) that can change the behaviour: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZLEJjdh3)

```sql
DO $anonymous_routine$
#variable_conflict error        --that's the default
#variable_conflict use_variable
#variable_conflict use_column   --if you enter all three, the last one will be used
DECLARE
  table_name text;
BEGIN
  FOR table_name IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'created_at' AND table_schema = 'public' LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN created_at TYPE timestamp without time zone;';
  END LOOP;
END $anonymous_routine$;
```

Another way to qualify things in PL/pgSQL is through the use of [*labels*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html#PLPGSQL-STRUCTURE) useful when you do actually mean the variable: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XGERx4Tr)

```sql
DO $anonymous_routine$
<<my_label>>
DECLARE table_name   text;
        table_schema text:='public';
        column_name  text:='created_at';
BEGIN
  FOR table_name IN SELECT ic.table_name 
                    FROM information_schema.columns AS ic 
                    WHERE  my_label.column_name  = ic.column_name
                    AND    my_label.table_schema = ic.table_schema
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || table_name || ' ALTER COLUMN created_at TYPE timestamp without time zone;';
  END LOOP;
END my_label $anonymous_routine$;
```

Note that `FOR table_name` isn't considered ambiguous because it's outside the context of that `SELECT` statement, where there's only your variable available under that name.